# wpf visibility based on a condition

Tags: wpf, datatrigger, stackpanel

I want to show a StackPanel based on a particular condition. In this example I've used the BorderThickness property:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="gridDati" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="12" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="pnlLoading" Visibility="Visible">
    <Label Content="">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, ElementName=gridDati, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, ElementName=gridDati, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="12">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="STAND BY" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Basically when in the code behind I apply a template on **gridDati**, while the item counter is still zero, the border is set correctly to 12. After that it turns to zero (item binded) and this behevior is what I want.

So, I also would like to show a StackPanel at the same condition, so I used a DataTrigger but seems that is not fired at all. How can I "link" these two condition? so show a stackpanel when I have items in the datagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way to declare the `Label` so you get the desired result.

```
<Label>
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="STAND BY"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

But there are a few points I need to explain to make sure you understand what I changed and why. I'm going to go through the XAML from the inside out.

First, I changed the `Setter` to use the right property name. You're using a `Label`, and your old `Setter` had `Property="TextBlock.Text"`. `TextBlock.Text` is not a valid property name for a `Label` (no such property exists), so that wasn't going to work. The property you want is called `Content`.

Moving up one level to the `DataTrigger`. Instead of binding to `gridDati` that is binding to `Items`, I just bound directly to `Items`. You *could* do it the other way, but in my opinion it would be unusual and it might cause unforeseen bugs.

Next, you'll notice I removed the first `DataTrigger`. WPF dependency properties can be set in a number of different ways, and there is an order of [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) for which value will be taken over others. The default value (lowest precedence) for a `Label`'s content is for it to be empty. When the `DataTrigger` applies the `Setter`, it overrides that value (it has higher precedence). When the `DataTrigger` condition is no longer fulfilled (`Items.Count != 0`), WPF stops applying the `Setter` and the value *reverts* back to the default, because there is no longer any value of higher precedence overriding it. So you don't need to add a second `DataTrigger` resetting to default, wit ill do that automatically.

Moving up further you'll see I changed the opening `Style` tag to `<Style TargetType="Label">`. It's common practice to set the `TargetType` of a `Style`. Doing this also gives you IntelliSense options for `Setter`s in that `Style`, which might have helpped you catch the mistake you made by trying to use `TextBlock.Text` as a property name.

Finally, I removed `Content=""` from the opening `Label` tag. Setting the value of a property directly on an element in XAML has a very high precedence, which overrides all `Style`s and `DataTrigger`s. As long as this was there, nothing you did in any `Style` would change anything for the `Label`'s `Content`.